# Does SaveChanges actually call DetectChanges?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm confusing about whether or not `context.SaveChanges` will call `DetectChanges` automatically. Most of books and blogs about Entity Framework said it would. But my simple code snippet. It seems like `SaveChanges` does not call `DetectChanges`.

```
using (var context = new BreakAwayContext())
{
     context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
     var grand = context.Destinations.Single(d => d.Name == "Grand Canyon");

     grand.Description = "Changed here";
     context.SaveChanges();                
}
```

This will not save changed property into database.

This will:

```
using (var context = new BreakAwayContext())
{
     context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
     var grand = context.Destinations.Single(d => d.Name == "Grand Canyon");

     grand.Description = "Changed here";
     context.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
     context.SaveChanges();                
}
```

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According Msdn reference(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556205.aspx)
 `context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;` will stop auto change detection from happening and thus `context.SaveChanges();` will not save any changes.

The correct ways of doing it are:

```
context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
//your changes starts
var grand = context.Destinations.Single(d => d.Name == "Grand Canyon");
grand.Description = "Changed here";
//your changes ends
context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true; //enabling the auto detect
context.SaveChanges();
```

OR (how you did it)

```
context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
//your changes starts
var grand = context.Destinations.Single(d => d.Name == "Grand Canyon");
grand.Description = "Changed here";
//your changes ends
context.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges(); // manually ask for changes detection
context.SaveChanges();
```

OR

do not set `context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled` to `false`, unless it becomes a performance issue.

Comment: http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2012/03/11/secrets-of-detectchanges-part-2-when-is-detectchanges-called-automatically/

DbSet.Find
DbSet.Local
DbSet.Remove
DbSet.Add
DbSet.Attach
DbContext.SaveChanges
DbContext.GetValidationErrors
DbContext.Entry
DbChangeTracker.Entries

These will call DetectChanges. Then why something like Add will add an object and mark it with state "Added"... Anyway, thank you for your answer.

Comment: Or you can use Dynamic Proxies which will work neither you enable or not AutoDetectChangesEnabled.

Comment: the blog already answers your query . The key here is _Lazy Implementation_  . `DetectChanges()` is a costly call and hence is done when it is a necessity instead of everytime changes are made. `DbSet.Find` , `DbSet.Remove` etc need to consider all the changes to work properly while `DbSet.Add` can do its job without calling `DetectChanges()`